# sum of [B G R] of pixels using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

`img = cv2.imread('example.png')`

`print(img[0][0],img[0][1],img[0][0]+img[0][0],(img[0][0]+img[0][0])/2)`

I'm trying to get the average of two pixels of example.png, however, it shows

[213 214 220] [195 218 225] **[170 172 184] [85. 86. 92.]**

instead of **[408 432 445] [204 216 222]**

Seems it automatically minus 256 for each element

the type of img is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: I'm going to guess that the dtype of the array is uint8. Which explains the overflow behaviour. The data type can't fit more than 256 so it wraps around using modulo arithmetic. You can check this by looking at `img.dtype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of pixel ranges from 0 to 255 because of the datatype `uint8`, which means the value will wrap when the value is out of range.

You could create an `np.array` and calculate `np.mean` along `axis=0`.

For example:

```
img = cv2.imread('example.png')
print(np.mean(np.array([img[0][0], img[0][0]], axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` has dtype `uint8`. This means that each value is stored as an unsigned integer in a byte in memory (8 bits). Such a number can only hold numbers from 0 to 255. If you try to go beyond that it will wrap around and start back from 0. This is what you describe as subtracting 256.

To work around this you can recast your values to float by doing.

```
mean_img = (img.astype(float)+img2.astype(float))/2

mean_img.astype("uint8") # recast back to uint 8
```